# Handle processes in c# update function

Tags: c#, sapb1

I'm an intern at a software company. I have an add-On programmed in c# for SAP B1. In this add-On i'm using my own update function due to some reasons(can't use clickOnce because of checksums in SAP). This update function is included in the main class. All other new functions I program are created as dll files.

Only one dll file called `"...main_functions.dll"` is included in the app in the beginning. And all other dll files can be added inside this dll file and upload in the ftp server .The app will download the new version of this "...main_functions.dll" file with other dll files and replaces the old files before the files are used by the app in the start up.

The problem is once this add-On is launched, it will be used in the same terminal in the customers' offices, which will make the add-on crash due to the fact that the app trying to replace a file which is currently being used by another user in the terminal. Now I'm trying to find a solution such as if there are processes running in the terminal by other users, stop the update process and display a message like "please close all other instances of this app before update begin!"

If someone can give me some ideas of solving this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming the C# part is made up of a series of Dll's with one being the entry point and that the SAP module just hooks into the dll's main function. So you should be able to deploy the C# part in isolation to any part of SAP. Introduce an installer project to the C# Solution this should take care of the issues you are talking about. If you dont want to 'Roll your own' there are plenty of third party ones such as InstallShield.

Comment: @bilpor The problem is this addOn is registered under SAP. Imagine it as a part of it once it registered. So using third-party solution for updating is quite impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution when rolling your own update process is that you have to have a separate process run to replace the DLLs your add-on uses, and be sure to exit your add-on before you try to replace the DLLs.

A good technique is to use the add-on to check if an update is available, then download the update to a temporary folder, and update only the separate process (if it needs updated).  Then, start the separate process and exit your add-on.  Have the separate process wait long enough to ensure your add-on has exited, then the separate process performs the update.

Comment: Hi Russ that is actually a good idea. I already have a way to check if an update is available. I have a .txt file in the ftp server which has the new version number stored. And every time the app starts it compares the ver. with the txt file in the local pc. I will try to use a separate process for update even though I'm still no that good with them :) Thanks

Comment: But if I use a sep. process for updating, regardless of the process, still there will be other processes which access the files(other users). Isn't it?

Comment: You do need to make sure no process is accessing any of the files you are updating, when you do the update, otherwise it will fail.

Comment: That's my original question. How can I avoid this problem?